# Determine whether a relation is a relation of equivalance or ordered relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am doing my homework and I was given three relations to determine whether they are ordered or relation of equivalance. Here's what I got as a result and my arguments, but neither of those relations are relation of equivalance for me, so I am thinking I must have got something wrong.

$(x,y) \in p, x \in Z, y \in Z, x-y \le 1 $

- It is reflexive, because every number substracted by itself is less than 1 (eg: $x=5,y=5 \text{ or } x=-5, y=-5$)
- It is not symmetric, because $(5, 10) \in p$, but $(10, 5) \notin p$, but it's antisymmetric.
- It is transitive, because $(5, 10)$ and $(10, 15)$ => $(5, 15)$

---

2. $(x,y) \in p, x \in Z, y \in Z, x^2=y^4$

- Not reflexive, because $4^2 \not= 4^4$
- Not symmetric, because $(2, 4) \notin p.\text{ but } (4,2) \in p$. It's also not antisymmetric.
- Not transitive, because $y^2\not=y^4$

---

3. $(x,y) \in p, x \in Z, y \in Z, x \text{ is even}, y \text{ is odd}$

- Not reflexive, because $(x, x) \notin p$
- Not symmetric, because $(2, 3) \in p$, but $(3, 2) \notin p$
- Not antisymmetric, because $(2, 2) \notin p$
- Not transitive, because $(2, 3) \in p$, but there's no $(3, y)$

Comment: You are correct that none of these relations is an equivalence relation.  I haven't checked all the assertions you make.

Comment: The 3rd relation is antisymmetric because if aRb then a is even and b is odd which means bRa does not hold because b is not even and a is not odd. Also, it is vacuously transitive because there exist no elements to contradict the transitivity property.

Comment: The last property of the third problem is incorrect. Transitivity states that if $(x,y)$ and $(y,z)$ are in the relation then $(x,z)$ is in the relation. You noted that $(3,y)$ is not in the relation but that does not contradict transitivity. This can also happen when you have a maximum element that is greater than all the others such as in a lattice. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)

Comment: In $2$ you assert that the relation is not antisymmetric but you give no reason for your claim (Indeed, you could just point to the pairs $(-1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$.)

Comment: In $1$ you claim the relation is antisymmetric, and yet both $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ are valid relations.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. @lulu To consider relation symmetric, shouldn't $aRb = bRa$ be be true for all pairs?

Comment: I didn't say it was symmetric. I was only addressing anti-symmetry.

Comment: the first relation is not transitive, since $(2,1)$ and $(1,0)$ provide a counterexample.

Comment: On the whole, I think you answered the questions much too hastily, and there are several careless errors as a result.  You can't prove that a property holds generally simply by giving one example of it working.  You can, of course, prove that a property *does not* hold generally by exhibiting a single counterexample.  I have stopped checking your claims, by the way.  Not sure all the errors have been identified in the comments.

Comment: The convention on this site is to ask one question per posting, showing your work. Asking "are these 10 claims correct?" does not match that convention. Please honor it in future questions.

Comment: @lulu Oh, my bad. Thanks for your help! I will recheck everything again and will stick to one problem per posting.